# how to make calculation between two rows in a specific column in a list

Tags: c#, csv

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace CsvDemo
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DailyValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Sample.csv")
                                       .Skip(1)
                                       .Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))
                                       .ToList();
    }
}

class DailyValues
{
    DateTime Date;
    decimal Open;
    decimal High;
    decimal Low;
    decimal Close;
    decimal Volume;
    decimal AdjClose;

    public static DailyValues FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        DailyValues dailyValues = new DailyValues();
        dailyValues.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
        dailyValues.Open = Convert.ToDecimal(values[1]);
        dailyValues.High = Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]);
        dailyValues.Low = Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]);
        dailyValues.Close = Convert.ToDecimal(values[4]);
        dailyValues.Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(values[5]);
        dailyValues.AdjClose = Convert.ToDecimal(values[6]);
        return dailyValues;
        }
    }
}
```

1. The `File.ReadAllLines` reads all lines from the CSV file into a string array.
2. The `.Skip(1)` skips the header line.
3. The `.Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))` uses Linq to select each line and create a new `DailyValues` instance using the `FromCsv` method. This creates a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CsvDemo.DailyValues>` type.
4. Finally, the `.ToList()` converts the IEnumerable to a List to match the type you want.

But my question is how can  I make a calculation between two cells. For example I want to addition in column 3 the rows 2 and 3 and the result be displayed in the last column.

Comment: From what you explained, it seems that you just have to iterate through `values` in `Main` and manually do your calculation. Is it a repetitive addition or just once? Depending on that, the approach will be different.

Comment: i have a csv file and i want to make an addition between two rows in a specific column and the result i want to display it in the last column. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you said that already, give us an example, using data, of the input and required output

Comment: what exactly do you mean by " I want to addition in column 3 the rows 2 and 3"?
If you want to add let's say the values of col 2 and 3, you can use result = values[1] + values[2]. you can place the result in another member variable so it's part of your list

Comment: i have a file like this: 
date,monthlySalary,yearlySalary 
2014-05-06,1000.50,14000.56 
2014-07-06,2058.65,28000.47 etc...     and i want to addition 2058.65+1000.50 and the result to be displayed in the fourth column in second row

Comment: 1) Update the question with more info, dont post it in comments 2) That csv example looks nothing like the one in your question

Comment: you could add the values, store it in an extra member variable and then iterate through the list, copying the added value in the corresponding col (field) of the next record (line).
do you hackers know a more elegant way? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (although, Im relying on a bit of mind-reading here) that you're trying to have a running balance field on each record of your list. You already have code which projects your raw csv data into a list of objects:

```
List<DailyValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Sample.csv")
                                   .Skip(1)
                                   .Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))
                                   .ToList()
```

What you need to do from there is to project it again into another list, doing the calculation as you go. Obviously this calculation cannot do anything with the first row, as it needs a previous value, so in that instance you set it to zero.

```
class DailyValuesWithTotal : DailyValues
{
    decimal TotalHigh
}
var projectedValues = values.Select( (v,i) => new DailyValuesWithTotal(){
    Date = v.Date,
    Open = v.Open,
    High = v.High,
    Low = v.Low,
    Volume = v.Volume,
    AdjClose = v.AdjClose,       
    TotalHigh = (i == 0) ? 0.0 : values[i-1].TotalHigh + v.High
})
```

The example above keeps a running total of the `High` field in a new field called `TotalHigh`.

Comment: yes something like this. I want to sum the currently high with the previous high and the result must be displayed in the currently result's row

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to sum the value of the current and next row to the current row last column.

If that's correct, you can do that with a for loop after you read all the data from the file. Just add a property in your class that you will fill in that for loop.

Comment: yes that's exactly i want to do! Can you help me a little bit with the property?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) or another CSV parsing library, since it will make your code a lot easier (especially error handling, handling quotes, etc.).

(I'll use this library in my answer, but you don't have to)

Add a new property to your class to store the calculated value:

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)] 
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class DailyValues
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")] 
    public DateTime Date;
    public decimal Open;
    public decimal High;
    public decimal Low;
    public decimal Close;
    public decimal Volume;
    public decimal AdjClose;
    [FieldNotInFile] 
    public decimal SomethingCalculated;
}
```

Then just loop through your elements and use a temporary variable to keep track of the value of the previous element you're interested in so you can do your calculation:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(DailyValues));
var res = engine.ReadFile(@"your:\path") as DailyValues[]; 

decimal? prev = null;
foreach(var value in res)
{
    if(prev.HasValue)
        // or whatever columns you want to use
        value.SomethingCalculated = value.High + prev.Value;
    prev = value.Open;
}
```